# Show hide div with animation

Tags: javascript, animation, html, show-hide

I made this script, which opens a div with the right class and close the others.

```
function showhide(id) {
    if (document.getElementById) {
        var divid = document.getElementById(id);
        var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("hideable");
        for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i = i + 1) {
            divs[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        divid.style.display = "block";
    }
    return false;
}
```

Is it possible to make some animation, like fadout, easeout instead of just showing it by display options?

Comment: Please help others help you, by formating your code samples.

Comment: Of course :) Do it man :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try this

```
function showhide(id) {
  if (document.getElementById) {
    var divid = document.getElementById(id);
    var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("hideable");
    for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i = i + 1) {
      $(divs[i]).fadeOut("slow");
    }
    $(divid).fadeIn("slow");
  }
  return false;
}
```

Have a look at this fiddle "http://jsfiddle.net/9jtd3/"

There are many more techniques provided by Jquery library, You should have a look at that too.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `slideDown() and slidUp()` of jQuery

```
$( document.body ).click(function () {
  if ( $( "div:first" ).is( ":hidden" ) ) {
    $( "div" ).slideDown( "slow" );
  } else {
    $( "div" ).slideUp("slow");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If You are using Jquery then another way to do this is

```
    function showhide(id) {
      $(".hideable").fadeOut("slow");
      $("#" + id).fadeIn("slow");
    }
```

Assuming "hideable" as className in your group of divs

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

This example will toggle multiple elements with the same class name.  This example does not need jquery.

### HTML:

```
<button onclick="fadeInAndOut(this)" style="width:100%">Toggle 1</button>
<div class="accordianPanel acordianPanelHidden accordianPanelStyle">Panel 1</div>

<button onclick="fadeInAndOut(this)" style="width:100%">Toggle 2</button>
<div class="accordianPanel acordianPanelHidden accordianPanelStyle">Panel 2</div>
```

### Javascript:

```
function fadeInAndOut(thz) {
  var elmt = thz.nextElementSibling;//Get the element that is below the button that
     //was just clicked

  elmt.classList.toggle("acordianPanelHidden");//Toggle the class which changes
    //attributes which triggers the `transition` CSS
}
```

### CSS

```
.accordianPanel {
  opacity: 1;
  height:100%;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.accordianPanel.acordianPanelHidden {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0px;
  visibility:hidden;/* This must be used or some strange things happen - 
   What happens is that even though the content of the panel is not shown 
   any buttons in the content can still be clicked -
   So basically there are invisible buttons that can accidently get clicked -
   if the visibility is not set to hidden - And the visibility doesn't need to be explicitly changed to visible
  from hidden in order to show the content
  because if visibility:hidden is not used then by default the content is 
  displayed -
 */
}

.acordianPanelShown {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
}

.accordianPanelStyle {
  background:red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/javascript-tutorial-simple-fade-animation)  will surely solve your problem.

You can use .fadeOut() directly if you have included jQuery library in your script.

Comment: Remote links may stop working. Please fix your answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is way easier with only CSS.

You make a class

```
div {
 display:block;
 transition: all .2s ease-out;
}

.hidden {
 display:none;
}
```

And with javascript, you apply or remove the class hidden when you want to. jQuery animation lib is wayyyy far from good to be used. It's clunky, and ressource eating for your user. CSS works with your GPU instead, allowing a more fluid animation.

Comment: `display` property isn't in the list of animated properties: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties

Comment: Instead of `display` the properties `opacity` or `visibility` could be used, depending on the requirements.

Answer (score -1):

You can do that using a Library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) or something.

You can sure make it using plain javascript, but there's no point doing that since jQuery is an amazing library.

See some examples of [show](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)