# Using Java script to collapse and uncollapse a div

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a snippet of HTML as below -

```
<div id = 'Div1' 
        style = 'height: 30px; width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 1px solid #7f7f7f; padding-left: 25px; font-size: 15px; color: #666666; 
             border-top-left-radius: 5px; border-top-right-radius: 5px; 
             display: flex; flex-direction: row; text-align: left; align-items: center; justify-content: left; position: relative;'>
  Header
  <div id = 'Div2'
       onclick = "{
                   var GetText = document.getElementById('Div2').innerHTML;
                   if (GetText == '&#8722;') {  
                   document.getElementById('Div1').style.borderBottom = '0px';
                   document.getElementById('Div3').offsetHeight = 1;
                   document.getElementById('Div2').innerHTML = '&#43;';
                   } else {
                   document.getElementById('Div1').style.borderBottom = '1px';
                   document.getElementById('Div3').offsetHeight = 'auto';
                   document.getElementById('Div2').innerHTML = '&#8722;';
                   }
                   };"
       style = 'margin: 0; padding: 0; position: absolute; right: 0; top: 0; height: 30px; width: 30px; color: #999999; cursor: pointer; 
                display: flex; flex-direction: row; text-align: center; align-items: center; justify-content: center; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.0);'>
    &#8722;
  </div>
</div>
<div id = 'Div3'
     style = 'height: auto; width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden; border: 1px solid #7f7f7f; border-top: 0px;
              border-bottom-left-radius: 5px; border-bottom-right-radius: 5px; '>
  <div style = 'height: auto; mim-height: 0px; width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; padding: 12px; font-size: 15px; color: #666666; 
                text-align: left; '>
    Answer
  </div>
</div>
```

My goal is if I click on `"-"` sign then the bottom portion will collapse and the `"-"` sign will change to `"+"`. But, when I click on `"+"` then opposite will happen.

With my above code, this is not clearly happening.

Can you please help me understand what went wrong?

Comment: For the love of any and all developers you have to maintain this code later, please use CSS classes and script elements.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show hide div with animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14335501/show-hide-div-with-animation)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the display property to hide/show the element. Like this:

```html
<div id = 'Div1' 
        style = 'height: 30px; width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 1px solid #7f7f7f; padding-left: 25px; font-size: 15px; color: #666666; 
             border-top-left-radius: 5px; border-top-right-radius: 5px; 
             display: flex; flex-direction: row; text-align: left; align-items: center; justify-content: left; position: relative;'>
  Header
  <div id = 'Div2'
       onclick = "{
                   var GetText = document.getElementById('Div2').innerHTML;
                   if (GetText == '&#8722;') {  
                   document.getElementById('Div1').style.borderBottom = '0px';
                   document.getElementById('Div3').offsetHeight = 1;
                   document.getElementById('Div3').style.height = '100px';
                   document.getElementById('Div2').innerHTML = '&#43;';
                   } else {
                   document.getElementById('Div1').style.borderBottom = '1px';
                   document.getElementById('Div3').offsetHeight = 'auto';
                   document.getElementById('Div3').style.height = '0px';
                   document.getElementById('Div2').innerHTML = '&#8722;';
                   }
                   };"
       style = 'margin: 0; padding: 0; position: absolute; right: 0; top: 0; height: 30px; width: 30px; color: #999999; cursor: pointer; 
                display: flex; flex-direction: row; text-align: center; align-items: center; justify-content: center; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.0);'>
    &#8722;
  </div>
</div>
<div id = 'Div3'
     style = 'height: auto; width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden; border: 1px solid #7f7f7f; border-top: 0px;
              border-bottom-left-radius: 5px; border-bottom-right-radius: 5px; '>
  <div style = 'height: auto; mim-height: 0px; width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; padding: 12px; font-size: 15px; color: #666666; 
                text-align: left; '>
    Answer
  </div>
</div>
```

UPDATE:

Instead of using the style property, you could use the height property:

```
document.getElementById('Div3').style.height = '100px';
document.getElementById('Div3').style.height = '0px';
```

Comment: I could use 'display' property, but I wanted to bring some sort of animation to increase and decrease the height gradually. Additionally, I dont see any change in the Border size of upper div as it appears like remaining same as 0px always

Comment: In that case, you could use the height property of the element directly. But I am not sure the border size issue. I have updated the code Snapshot. I hope this helps you in some way.

Comment: You should probably edit the text of your answer when you change the code...

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the block/none styling properties to hide or show the element. You can use a boolean and run a if/else loop to toggle between '-' and '+', on the Event listener function. Hope this helps, if you want any more assistance feel free to ping me!

Answer (score 0):

Please Change

```
document.getElementById('Div3').offsetHeight = 1;
```

to

```
 document.getElementById('Div3').style.height = '1px';
```

And

```
document.getElementById('Div3').offsetHeight = 'auto';
```

to

```
document.getElementById('Div3').style.height = 'auto';
```